# What is difference between object and data class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

What is difference between data and object class in Kotlin, and what is the purpose of each?

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

and

```
object user {
    val name = ""
    fun printName(name: String) = "Hello, $name!"
}
```

Comment: Other than that they are both language features of Kotlin, they are largely unrelated, IMHO.

`data class` is a particular type of class, one that generates a lot of functions for you: `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `copy()`, etc. `data class` has a number of restrictions as a result, such as needing all of its constructor parameters to be `val`.

`object` creates a singleton.

Comment: @SamirMangroliya, great question! I think for people who are starting learning Kotlin have the same doubts you experienced at some point.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### `object`

`object` is Kotlin's way to create a singleton (one instance class) which is instantiated by the compiler.

---

### `data class`

A data class is like a usual class but with a few advantages/resctrictions ([Source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)).

**Advantages**

- `equals()`/`hashCode()`
- `toString()`
- `componentN()`
- `copy()`

Those are created from the properties specified in the primary constructor.

**Restrictions**

- The primary constructor needs to have at least one parameter;
- All primary constructor parameters need to be marked as val or var;
- cannot be abstract, open, sealed or inner;
- (before 1.1) may only implement interfaces.

Answer (score 10):

Kotlin's `object` is similar to a class in Java, where all methods and variables are static.

```
object User {
    val name = ""
    fun printName(name: String) = "Hello, $name!"
}
```

in Kotlin is similar to the following in Java:

```
class User {
    public static String name = "";
    public static String printName(name: String) {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
//Kotlin
User.printName(User.name)

//Java
User.printName(User.name);
```

An `object` isn't exactly the same as the Java comparison I gave, though. It can inherit interfaces and classes, and the object itself is instantiated as a singleton instance. If you annotate methods inside an object with `@JvmStatic`, they will become true static members.

[Kotlin's object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations)

---

The `data` class in Kotlin is just a simpler syntax for a class that has no (or minimal) logic, and contains certain values. Kotlin generates the `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `toString()` functions for you in a data class, along with some other helper functions.

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: String)
```

in Kotlin will look something like this in Java:

```
class User {
    public final String name;
    public final String age;

    public User(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        //Kotlin-generated equality check
    }

    @Override
    public long hashCode() {
        //Kotlin's hashcode
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return "User(name=" + name + ",age=" + age + ")";
    }

    //other generated methods
}
```

[Kotlin's data class documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)

Comment: Upvoted for showing that there actually is an "object" keyword in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no *object class*, the feature you are referring to is called **object declaration**.

#### [Object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations)

This is a feature in Kotlin that allows you implement a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). The object declaration combines a class declaration and a declaration of a single instance of the class in a single statement.

```
// Let's assume that class Person is defined somewhere else
object Payroll {
    val employees = arrayListOf<Person>()

    fun calculateSalary() {
        for (person in employees) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

// calling methods and properties
>>> Payroll.employees.add(Person("John", 23)) // calling a property
>>> Payroll.calculateSalary() // calling a method
```

Just like a class, an object declaration can contain declarations of *properties, methods, initializer blocks,* and so on. The only thing they are not allowed are **constructors** (either primary or secondary).

Object declarations are created immediately at the point of the definition, not through constructor calls from other places in the code.

**Note:** the `object` keyword can also be used for [*companion objects*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) and [*object expressions*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions).

#### [Data Class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)

It is very common to create classes whose main goal is to hold data. If you want your class to be a convenient holder for your data you need to override the universal object methods:

- `toString()` - string representation
- `equals()` - object equality
- `hashCode()` - hash containers

However, by adding the modifier data to your class, the necessary methods are automatically added for you. In addition, the following methods are also generated:

- `componentN()` functions corresponding to the properties in their order of declaration
- `copy()` function

```
class PersonClass(val name: String, val age: Int) // regular class
data class PersonDataClass(val name: String, val age: Int) // data class
```

In summary, if you need a holder for data, you should use a data class which means adding the modifier data to your class. This will generate the following methods for you: `toString()`, `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `componentN()`, and `copy()`, so you avoid writing boilerplate code. On the other hand, if you need to create a singleton, you use the object declaration feature.

Answer (score 0):

In short, object is used, if you want to create singleton, unique object for the class and data class is a class that has `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString` automatically generated.